# Custom NSButton Focus Ring Color

Tags: objective-c, xcode, focus, subclass, nsbutton

I've subclassed a NSButton and NSButtonCell, I've changed the drawings. Now the focus ring no longer appears on the button. I'm looking for a way to draw a focus ring with a custom color, on my custom button.

**Question Updated**

Comment: The focus ring is drawn by the cell class isn't it?  What methods does your subclass implement that could have broken this?

Comment: I've subclassed NSButtonCell as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of how to draw the focus ring yourself (so you do a custom color), but to have your custom button cell draw the focus ring you usually only need to override [focusRingMaskBoundsForFrame:inView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/focusRingMaskBoundsForFrame%3ainView%3a) like this:

```
- (NSRect)focusRingMaskBoundsForFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    return cellFrame;
}
```

If that doesn't give you the result you wanted, you might need to additionally provide a mask by implementing [drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame:inView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame%3ainView%3a). In this method you basically just draw what should get a focus ring added. Cocoa does the rest for you.

Note that these methods only work for Mac OS X 10.7 Lion and higher, but this is how Apple says it should be done now.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work at all - those methods weren't called so I had to revert to pre-10.7 ways of drawing the focus ring.  There doesn't appear to be any help about it either on the net.

Answer (score -2):

You can add Tracking area for your custom button class and then you can customize your button focus.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
int opts = (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways);
NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.frame options:opts owner:self userInfo:nil];
[self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}
```

Now you can do your customization in the following functions.

```
- (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)event{
        //Add Custom Focus Ring
}

- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent*)event{
        //Remove Custom Focus Ring
}
```

Comment: I think, there is no other way than this. Or you can try like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118932/nsbutton-image-shadow-on-mouseentered-event/12802496#12802496

Comment: You didn't fully understand my question. I asked for Focus Ring. It is different from hover effect.